# Hints to find solution of : $\left\lfloor \frac{x}{100} \left\lfloor \frac{x}{100}\right\rfloor \right\rfloor=5$

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find the number of integer solution of $$\left\lfloor  \dfrac{x}{100} \left\lfloor \dfrac{x}{100}\right\rfloor \right\rfloor=5$$

$\lfloor . \rfloor$ is Greatest Integer Function or floor function.

Comment: Replace $x$ with $100a + b$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:  focusing first on the inner floor, clearly we must have $0 \lt \lfloor \frac x{100} \rfloor \lt 3$, so it can only be $1$ or $2$.  If it is $1$, how large can the product inside the outer floor be?  If it is $2$, what range of $x$ works?

Comment: please explain your first argument.

Comment: As $\frac x{100} \ge \lfloor \frac x{100} \rfloor$, if $\lfloor \frac x{100} \rfloor \ge 3$ the left side of the equation will be at least $9$.

Answer (score 2):

As $y-1<\lfloor y\rfloor\le y $, we find that for $y\ge1$
$$\tag1y^2-y-1<\lfloor y\lfloor y\rfloor\rfloor\le y^2 $$
whereas for $y<0$, we have
$$\tag2y^2-y-1>\lfloor y\lfloor y\rfloor\rfloor\ge y^2 $$
Finally, for $0\le y<1$, we clearly have $\lfloor y\lfloor y\rfloor \rfloor=0$
Thus we cannot have $\lfloor y\lfloor y\rfloor\rfloor=5$ with $y\le -\sqrt 5$ (right hand side of $(2)$), nor with $-2\le y<0$ (left hand side of $(2)$), nor with $0\le y<1$, nor with $1\le y<\sqrt 5$ (right hand side of $(1)$), nor with $y\ge 3$ (left hand side of $(1)$). In other words, $-\sqrt 5< y <-2$ or $\sqrt 5\le y<3$. Then $\lfloor y\rfloor =-3$ or $\lfloor y\rfloor=2$.

In the first case, $$-3y-1<\lfloor -3y\rfloor=\lfloor y\lfloor  y\rfloor \rfloor \le -3y,$$
so that we need $y\ge -\frac 53$, which contardicts $y<-2$.

In the second case
$$2y-1<\lfloor 2y\rfloor=\lfloor y\lfloor  y\rfloor \rfloor \le 2y,$$
so that we need $y\ge\frac 52$. And indeed, for $\frac25\le y<3$, we verify directly that $\lfloor y\lfloor y \rfloor\rfloor=5 $.
If we impose that $y=\frac x{100}$ with $x\in\Bbb Z$, this is equivalent to $$250\le x<300$$
whic allows exactly $50$ differnet values of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

First note that as $[n] \le n < [n]+1$

then $[n]^2 \le [n[n]] < ([n]+1)^2$

So $[x/100]^2 \le [n[n]]= 5 < ([x/100] + 1)^2$.  As $[x/100]$ is an integer, this means $[x/100] = 2$

So

$[x/100[x/100]]= [x/100*2] = [x/50] = 5$

$5 \le  x/50 < 6$

$250 \le x < 300$ so $x = [250.... 299]$.

Comment: how to get second argument?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: explain deeply: $[n]^2 \le [n[n]] < ([n]+1)^2$

Comment: [n] < = n so [n][n] <= n [n] so [[n][n]]=[n][n] <= [n [n]].  And n < [n]+1 so  [n [n]] < = n^2 < ([n]+1)^2.

Answer (score 1):

$\lfloor\frac{{x}}{\mathrm{100}}\lfloor\frac{{x}}{\mathrm{100}}\rfloor\rfloor=\mathrm{5}\:\Rightarrow\lfloor\frac{{x}}{\mathrm{100}}\rfloor=\lfloor\sqrt{\mathrm{5}}\rfloor=\mathrm{2} \\ $
$\lfloor\frac{{x}}{\mathrm{100}}.\mathrm{2}\rfloor=\mathrm{5}\Rightarrow\frac{{x}}{\mathrm{50}}\in\left[\mathrm{5},\mathrm{6}\right) \\ $
${x}\in\left[\mathrm{250},\mathrm{300}\right) \\ $

Comment: A likely math typo: I think you mean "$2\implies\lfloor{x\over100}2\rfloor$" instead of just $2\lfloor{x\over100}2\rfloor$ (and it looks like you omitted another "$\implies$" after "$[5,6)$").

Comment: I mean (x/100)×2., and I don't really know there are special use of arrow..

Comment: And I don't know to make space in this comment...

Comment: you used the arrow correctly (to mean "implies") in two places, you just omitted it in two other places. The first omission results in what looks like incorrect equalities between $\lfloor\sqrt5\rfloor$, $2\lfloor{x\over100}\cdot2\rfloor$, and $5$.